# How to make a listView display only the first item?

Tags: android, listview

I have tried setting the 'layout_height' of ListView to 'wrap_content', as suggested by someone on stack overflow, but it didn't work.
Please suggest a solution for this.

Comment: Post your code here

Comment: What do you mean? If you want only one item, then load one item to adapter. Maybe set getItemCount() or getCount() to return 1, I don't know.

Comment: If you want your list to show only one item then just create new list and add only one item the one you want to show then give it to the adapter.

And if you want to display one item at a time then set fix recyclerview height.

Comment: Thanks all of you.

Comment: @Samar, thanks for pointing out the direction. Solved the problem.